# how to create a API for user model in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am Trying To create a API for my custom user model to register a user and get details about current user that is logged in .
I tried to Follow a tutorial but I faced 2 problems, 1.The confirmation password is not being hashed when creating a user, 2. The Get method didn't work ( I was Trying to Get User details Using the id, it didn't return any thing except bad request responce ).
I hope any one can help me.

This is my models.py:

```py
from django.db import models
from django import forms
# Create your models here.

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    AbstractUser,
    BaseUserManager,
    AbstractBaseUser
    )
from django.forms import Widget
from django.urls import reverse
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self,email,password=None,is_active=True,is_staff=False,is_admin=False):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('User Must Have Email')
        if not password:
            raise ValueError('User Must Have Password')
        user_obj = self.model(
            email = self.normalize_email(email)
        )
        user_obj.set_password(password)#change user password
        user_obj.staff = is_staff
        user_obj.admin = is_admin
        user_obj.active = is_active
        user_obj.save(using=self._db)   
        return user_obj
    def create_staffuser(self,email,password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            password = password,
            is_staff = True
        )
        return user
    def create_superuser(self,email,password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            password = password,
            is_staff = True,
            is_admin = True,
        )
        return user
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    username          = models.CharField(max_length= 200)
    first_name        = models.CharField(max_length = 300)
    last_name         = models.CharField(max_length = 300)
    email             = models.EmailField(max_length=255,unique=True)   
    password          = models.CharField(max_length=100,)
    password_2        = models.CharField(max_length=100,)
    sub_to_newsletter = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    own_pc            = models.BooleanField(default=False) 
    active            = models.BooleanField(default=True)  #can login
    staff             = models.BooleanField(default=False) #staff user not superuser
    admin             = models.BooleanField(default=False) #admin / superuser
    
    USERNAME_FIELD  = 'email' #username
    #email and password is requierd by default
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [] #python manage.py createsuperuser
    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.email
    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email
    def has_perm(self,perm,obj=None):
        return True
    def has_module_perms(self,app_label):
        return True
    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.staff
    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.admin
    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active
    def get_absolute_url(request):
        return reverse('')
```

This is my forms.py:

```py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.forms import ReadOnlyPasswordHashField
User = get_user_model()

class UserAdminCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    A form for creating new users. Includes all the required
    fields, plus a repeated password.
    """
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    password_2 = forms.CharField(label='Confirm Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email']

    def clean(self):
        '''
        Verify both passwords match.
        '''
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        password = cleaned_data.get("password")
        password_2 = cleaned_data.get("password_2")
        if password is not None and password != password_2:
            self.add_error("password_2", "Your passwords must match")
        return cleaned_data

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user


class UserAdminChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for updating users. Includes all the fields on
    the user, but replaces the password field with admin's
    password hash display field.
    """
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'password']

    def clean_password(self):
        # Regardless of what the user provides, return the initial value.
        # This is done here, rather than on the field, because the
        # field does not have access to the initial value
        return self.initial["password"]
```

This is admin.py:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from .models import *
from .forms import *
User = get_user_model()
# Register your models here.
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    # The forms to add and change user instances
    form = UserAdminChangeForm
    add_form = UserAdminCreationForm

    # The fields to be used in displaying the User model.
    # These override the definitions on the base UserAdmin
    # that reference specific fields on auth.User.
    list_display = ['email', 'admin']
    list_filter = ['admin']
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        ('Personal info', {'fields': ('username','first_name','last_name','sub_to_newsletter','own_pc')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('admin',)}),
    )
    # add_fieldsets is not a standard ModelAdmin attribute. UserAdmin
    # overrides get_fieldsets to use this attribute when creating a user.
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'password', 'password_2')}
        ),
    )
    search_fields = ['email']
    ordering = ['email']
    filter_horizontal = ()


admin.site.register(User,UserAdmin)
```

Comment: 1. Where are you checking if the confirm password is hashed? Did you check the password as well? Is it hashed at the same place you check the confirm password? 2. What do you mean by "get method didn't work"? What was the exact GET request you tried? And what happened? What was the status code and body of the reply? Were there any error messages? If so, what were they? Please [edit] your question to include these details.

Comment: I wanted to hash the confirm password using the same way that Django does but I cant figure it out, and Yes I found that that the password is hashed when I view it from admin panel.
can you just tell me the best way to register a new user and get the info using a API ?
if you have like a video or something.

Comment: There is no reason to store the "confirm password" on your user model. Instead, this  is a mechanism to prevent typos and ensure that the password is what the user thought they typed. You should compare the "confirm password" with the password before allowing the user to change their password. But then you only need to store the password once. If you insist on storing the confirm password, you can look at the code for `set_password()` to see how Django hashes the password.

Comment: Can you edit my code to make this happen please ?
because I tried but i am little beginner in API's and stuff

Comment: Thanks for adding more details. However, I need to see the exact output rather than a summary of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you remove `password_2` from your user model. There is no reason to store the password twice. The purpose of a "confirm password" is to force the user to enter the same password twice in order to eliminate typos.

You can keep `password_2` as a form field. Then add [field validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/validation/) to check that `password` and `password_2` are the same.

Comment: But i am trying to build a API , how to add this to a API ?

Comment: @omarshokry I suggest you check out Django REST Framework for building a REST API.

Comment: Ok thanks , do you have any links to learn more about this ?

Comment: @omarshokry If you start with google, the first hit should be the official docs for Django REST Framework.